# Android Relativelayout Custom Dialog Problems

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, customdialog

I need some help with my relativelayout. My "Close" button cant be seen when i launch my custom dialog. It can only be seen when i set my ScollView Height to around "200dp" . I do not want to manually set the height. Is there a way to accomplish it? Maybe using android:weightSum? Please show me how it is done. Thanks

```
OnMenuItemClickListener mAboutButtonClickListener = new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

         @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {  

                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainPageActivity.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.about_us);
                dialog.setTitle("About Us");
                dialog.setCancelable(true);

                TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);

                try {
                    Resources res = getResources();
                    InputStream in_s = res.openRawResource(R.raw.disclaimer);

                    byte[] b = new byte[in_s.available()];
                    in_s.read(b);
                    text.setText(new String(b));

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // e.printStackTrace();
                    text.setText("Error: can't show help.");
                }


                //set up button
                Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
                button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                    dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });


                dialog.show();
                return false;
            }
        };
```

My xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
              >

        <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01" 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical" 
                    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">

        <TextView   android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </ScrollView>

        <Button android:id="@+id/Button01" 
                android:layout_below="@+id/ScrollView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
                android:text="Close"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you probably can force you button visible by aligning it to the bottom of the relative layout

Comment: alignParentBottom="true"

Comment: its still not showing. I've edited my codes

Comment: use hierarchyviewer to see where you button has gone. you relativelayout may be too large. fill_parent would limit that to the size of the screen

Comment: I've set my relativelayout to fill_parent . My button still cant be seen. I know my relativelayout is large. But i need to force my button below so users get it to click on it

Comment: did you try to use A/ linearlayout instead? B/ see what happens exactly with hierarchy viewer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/root"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="0dip"
  android:layout_weight="1" >

 <TextView   android:id="@+id/TextView01"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 </ScrollView>

 <Button android:id="@+id/Button01" 
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:text="Close" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this did it. does defining android:layout_height="0dip" effect on other smaller screen size phones?

Comment: you can try out with smaller screen emulators and see. Scrollview height adjusted according to the screen size.

Comment: wow....finally...been working on this layout I needed, and just couldn't figure it out. This helped me a lot. The catch was with the ScrollView which I should have used.