# I want to show my login form in dialog box or in pop up box using android

Tags: android

I have two textViews in one xml ie. Customer login and Suppliers login...When i am clicking on cuztomer login or suppliers login pop up should open on that I want to show my login form.
Help me out please.

Here is my login form:login_layout.xml

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/header_layout" />
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_username"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="@string/username"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_username"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:hint="@string/enter_username"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_password"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:gravity="center"
             android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="@string/password"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_password"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:hint="@string/enter_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:singleLine="true" />
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_forgot"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="@string/forgot_password"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loginButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:text="@string/login"
             />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is LoginActivity.java:

```
package com.Login;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText etUsername, etPassword;
    private Button loginButton;
    private JSONParser jsonParser;
    private static String loginURL = "http://www.xyz.com?login.php";

    private Bundle bundle;
    private String success;
    /** The dialog. */
    private ProgressDialog dialog;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_layout);

        TextView textv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_forgot);
        textv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(v.getContext(), ForgotPassActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        intitDisplay();
        addListeners();

    }

    private void addListeners() {
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (etUsername.getText().length() == 0)
                    etUsername.setError("please enter username");

                if (etPassword.getText().length() == 0)
                    etPassword.setError("please enter password");

                if ((etUsername.getText().length() > 0)
                        && (etPassword.getText().length() > 0)) {
                    jsonParser = new JSONParser();

                    if (jsonParser.isNetworkAvailable(LoginActivity.this)) {
                        new BackgroundTask().execute();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,
                                "Network not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                }

            }
        });

    }

    private void intitDisplay() {
        etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_username);
        etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);
        loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        bundle = new Bundle();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login_layout, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /** calling web service to get creditors list */
    /**
     * The Class BackgroundTask.
     */
    private class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        /** The resp. */
        String resp;

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPreExecute()
         */
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();

        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see android.os.AsyncTask#doInBackground(Params[])
         */
        protected String doInBackground(final String... args) {

            Log.v("ENTERED USERNAME::", "" + etUsername.getText().toString());
            String newUrl = loginURL + "username="
                    + etUsername.getText().toString() + "&password="
                    + etPassword.getText().toString();
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(newUrl);

            try {
                success = json.getString("msg");
                Log.v("SUCCESS:: ", success);
                if (success.trim().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("SUCCESS")) {
                    String loggedUsername = json.getString("USER_NAME");
                    bundle.putString("loggedUser", loggedUsername);
                    Log.v("Logged User::", loggedUsername);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
         */
        protected void onPostExecute(String list) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            if (success.trim().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("SUCCESS")) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Succesfull..",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                        HomeActivity.class).putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login failed...",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use an alert dialog with two edittexts and buttons to ask for login.

Comment: @Renjith I want to show whole log in form in that popup box.

Comment: Follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138454/android-relativelayout-custom-dialog-problems/12138557#12138557. This will help u

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Use this**

Create a new xml file which has the textfields,edittexts,buttons i.e. your login form that you want to show in the popup.Now call the following method where you want to show the popup.

```
private void callLoginDialog() 
     {
         myDialog = new Dialog(this);
         myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.yourxmlfileID);
         myDialog.setCancelable(false);
         Button login = (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.yourloginbtnID);

          emailaddr = (EditText) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.youremailID);
          password = (EditText) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.yourpasswordID);
          myDialog.show();

         login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
         {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                    //your login calculation goes here
            }
        });


     }
```

Let me know if it helps you....

Answer (score 2):

Apply `@android:style/Theme.Dialog` to your login activity. You can do that in the Manifest editor.

Comment: + 1 for easy and perfect solution .

Answer (score 2):

In your manifest file give like this

```
<activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
              android:label="Login"
              android:theme="@style/CustomDialogTheme"
              android:configChanges="locale|keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
```

and in styles.xml give the customDialogTheme as

```
   <style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:bottomBright">#fff</item>
    <item name="android:bottomDark">#fff</item>
    <item name="android:bottomMedium">#fff</item>
    <item name="android:centerBright">#fff</item>
    <item name="android:centerDark">#fff</item>
    <item name="android:centerMedium">#fff</item>
    <item name="android:fullBright">#7D266A</item>
    <item name="android:fullDark">#7D266A</item>
    <item name="android:topBright">#2f6699</item>
    <item name="android:topDark"#2f6699</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I am using your code but I am having following error in styles.xml. "error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:bottomDark' with value '@color/white')."

Comment: yes you should maintain colors.xml in values folder. other wise just place #fff in place of white color

Answer (score 1):

Use custom dialog.

create layouts for **Customer** and **Suppliers**

Show custom dialog dialog on click according to your requirement.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customerlogin);
```

or

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.supplierlogin);

dialog.show();
```